# Bad Question Pls Ignore. Why are my results not showing up in excel? Reason: Excel Cell Character limit length exceeded

Tags: excel, vba

**The ONLY issue with the code not working in the first place was the fact the number of results returning for each cell was over excels cell character limit (which would be another question). Otherwise my code is working and the question unnecessary .

The actual issue was excels cell character limit.

This could be solved for my purposes by changing the size of the array I was returning values from.

When I shrank the 2 dimensional range to search in, or the value I was searching for was less popular/more unique in the array, or indeed in some cases removed my wildcards (performed stricter searches), the results (being less then 32767 characters in length) started to be returned\become visible.

So the entire original question was unnecessary. Should have been more about returned result visability when result character length exceeds excels cell character limit. I should had checked/realised that by myself first .(Sunday night)

----- This was the question:

I am trying to convert cell addresses into the cell content (or values).

```
If UCase(xCell.value) Like SearchTerm Then
    FunctionT = FunctionT & Range(Range(xCell.Address(0, 0)).row, Range(xCell.Address(0, 0)).Column).Text & " // "
```

It can return the row numbers and column numbers of these addresses, and cell addresses, but can't return the content of these cells. Why is that?

Have tried range.value, and range.text.

At least I have the Row and Column numbers.

But it doesn't work when I try:

```
Cells(Range(xCell.Address(0, 0)).row, Range(xCell.Address(0, 0)).Column).value
```

or even just

```
Cells(Range(xCell.Address(0, 0)).row, Range(xCell.Address(0, 0)).Column)
```

### I was expecting the output of the contents of those cells, instead I just got #value. [SOLVED (because of character limit)]

Comment: I expected, as I stated, the cell contents, values or what was in the cells .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but give this a try.

Replace the line with:

```
FunctionT = FunctionT & Cells(Range(xCell.Address(0, 0)).Row, Range(xCell.Address(0, 0)).Column).Value & " // "
```

Comment: That is what I am doing and it is not working. I've said it in my question.

Comment: Post the whole code, maybe the problem is the variable definition or what you you have in the actual cell

Answer (score -2):

When the size of array was changed (decreased),  or the uniqueness of the item to be searched for increased,

```
            FunctionT = FunctionT & Range(xcell.Address(0, 0)).value & "//"
```

and/or

```
         FunctionT = FunctionT & xCell.Value & "//"
```

Worked perfectly.

**The ONLY issue with it not working in the first place was the fact the number of results returning for each cell was over excels cell character limit which would be another question.**

Comment: Is this the answer to your own problem?

Comment: Much toooo complicated! If the range "xCell" represents e. g. A1, then `Address(0,0)` is interpreted as `Address(False, False)`, which results in "A1". So it's just `FunctionT = FunctionT & xCell.Value & "//"`

Comment: Both         

                
             
    xCell.Value  

and 
                  
              
        Range(xcell.Address(0, 0)).value 


work, and originally even, did work, but the problem resulting in #value seemed to be only the number of returns was exceeding the cell content limit which is why I was getting #value.

No one thought of that. I should have tested it originally and wouldnt have asked the question. Instead question would have been, how to show returns even if cell limit exceeded.

Comment: I suggest to delete the original question, as itself and the "solution" is completely misleading.

Comment: How is it so?? No one asked the question of the area range this was being carried out on, or the number of data values / number of returns expected.  Which was the only reason it was returning #value for any valid vba syntax or code I used . ~18000 characters. I have figured out a solution to this too.

Comment: Cell limit is 32767 characters. Addressing it by `Range(xcell.Address(0, 0)).value` or `xcell.Value` is NO DIFFERENCE. If you found out something else of interest, you are welcome, but then PLEASE adapt your question and your answer, that other people may get the point also.

Comment: How about dumping results over 32767 on a new sheet